# Better query for iterating API requests for each row of a CSV file?

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I'm asking if there is a better python query than mine, that can allow better processing time. I'm iterating REST API requests for each row of a CSV file and exporting results into a new CSV file. When I ran 10 rows, it took about 11 seconds. But I need to do 50,000 rows. So I'm guessing it would take 
about 14 hours (833 minutes = 50,000 seconds).

Is there any way that I can reduce the processing time? (any query improvement?) Thanks!

Note: This API can determine whether an individual address is up to date by inputting individual address, first name, last name, etc.

### Python query

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

# Input CSV
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000.csv",delimiter = ',' , na_values="nan")
   # Writing first, last name column
splitted = df['prop_yr_owner_name'].str.split()
df['last_name'] = splitted.str[0]
df['first_name'] = splitted.str[1]

print(df["first_name"].iloc[0])



# Output CSV
with open(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_output.csv", 'w',  newline='') as fp:
    # Writing Header
    fieldnames = ["AddressExtras","AddressLine1","AddressLine2","BaseMelissaAddressKey","City","CityAbbreviation","MelissaAddressKey","MoveEffectiveDate","MoveTypeCode","PostalCode","State","StateName","NameFirst", "NameFull", "NameLast", "NameMiddle", "NamePrefix", "NameSuffix"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

# Iterating requests for each row
for row in df.itertuples():
    url = 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover' 
    payload = {'t': '1353', 'id': '4t8hsfh8fj3jf', 'jobid': '1', 'act': 'NCOA, CCOA', 'cols': 'TotalRecords,AddressExtras,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,,BaseMelissaAddressKey,City,CityAbbreviation,MelissaAddressKey,MoveEffectiveDate,MoveTypeCode,PostalCode,RecordID,Results,State,StateName, NameFirst, NameFull, NameLast, NameMiddle, NamePrefix, NameSuffix', 'opt': 'ProcessingType: Standard', 'List': 'test', 'first': row.first_name, 'last': row.last_name, 'a1': row.prop_year_addr_line1, 'a2': row.prop_year_addr_line2, 'city': row.prop_addr_city, 'state': row.prop_addr_state, 'postal': row.prop_addr_zip, 'ctry': 'USA'}

    response = requests.get(
        url, params=payload,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )

    r = response.json()
    print(r)

    output_1 = r['Records'][0]['AddressExtras']
    output_2 = r['Records'][0]['AddressLine1']
    output_3 = r['Records'][0]['AddressLine2']
    output_4 = r['Records'][0]['BaseMelissaAddressKey']
    output_5 = r['Records'][0]['City']
    output_6 = r['Records'][0]['CityAbbreviation']
    output_7 = r['Records'][0]['MelissaAddressKey']
    output_8 = r['Records'][0]['MoveEffectiveDate']
    output_9 = r['Records'][0]['MoveTypeCode']
    output_10 = r['Records'][0]['PostalCode']
    output_11 = r['Records'][0]['State']
    output_12 = r['Records'][0]['StateName']
    output_13 = r['Records'][0]['NameFirst']
    output_14 = r['Records'][0]['NameFull']
    output_15 = r['Records'][0]['NameLast']
    output_16 = r['Records'][0]['NameMiddle']
    output_17 = r['Records'][0]['NamePrefix']
    output_18 = r['Records'][0]['NameSuffix']

    output_list = [output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4, output_5, output_6, output_7, output_8, output_9, output_10, output_11, output_12, output_13, output_14, output_15, output_16, output_17, output_18 ]
    print (output_list)

    with open(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_output.csv", 'a', newline='') as fp:
        csv.writer(fp).writerow(output_list)
```

### Sample JSON API result for one row

> {'CASSReportLink': 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/Reports/CASSReport.aspx?tkenrpt=YvBDs39g52jKhLJyl5RgHKpuj5HwDMe1pE2lcQrczqRiG3/3y5yMlixj5S7lIvLJpDyAOkD8fE8vDCg56s3UogNuAkdTbS2aqoYF5FvyovUjnXzoQaHaL8TaQbwyCQ2RB7tIlszGy5+LqFnI7Xdr6sjYX93FDkSGei6Omck5OF4=', 'NCOAReportLink': 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/Reports/NCOAReport.aspx?tkenrpt=8anQa424W7NYg8ueROFirapuj5HwDMe1pE2lcQrczqRiG3/3y5yMlixj5S7lIvLJpDyAOkD8fE8vDCg56s3UogNuAkdTbS2aqoYF5FvyovUjnXzoQaHaL8TaQbwyCQ2RB7tIlszGy5+LqFnI7Xdr6sjYX93FDkSGei6Omck5OF4=', 'Records': [{'AddressExtras': '', 'AddressKey': '78704,78704', 'AddressLine1': '                                                            ,                                                            ,                                                            ,STE C-100                                                   ', 'AddressLine2': '1009 W MONROE ST                                            ,1600 S 5TH ST                                               ,1008 W MILTON ST                                            ,3939 BEE CAVES RD                                           ', 'AddressTypeCode': '', 'BaseMelissaAddressKey': '', 'CarrierRoute': '', 'City': 'Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ', 'CityAbbreviation': 'Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ', 'CompanyName': '', 'CountryCode': 'US', 'CountryName': 'United States', 'DeliveryIndicator': '', 'DeliveryPointCheckDigit': '', 'DeliveryPointCode': '', 'MelissaAddressKey': '', 'MoveEffectiveDate': '', 'MoveTypeCode': '', 'PostalCode': '78704,78704,78704,78746', 'RecordID': '1', 'Results': 'AE07', 'State': '', 'StateName': 'TX                                                ,TX                                                ,TX                                                ,TX                                                ', 'Urbanization': ''}], 'TotalRecords': '1', 'TransmissionReference': '1353', 'TransmissionResults': '', 'Version': '4.0.4.48'}
>   [Finished in 2.6s]

Comment: The most obvious speedup would be parallelization. Is there anything in your data or API that would prevent you from processing many rows simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly two performance pitfalls:

1. Making a single request for each row.
2. Opening the file every time to append information.

## Regarding the first point

This is a guess but you're probably launching many HTTP requests. One way of improving that part is batching them in bigger requests (a single request ideally). This way you can avoid a significant amount of overhead related with connection setup between your PC and the server. I don't know if that url allows request batching but you should definitely research about it if you plan requesting 50 thousand rows (Guessing you're planning to launch all the requestes inside that loop).

## Regarding the second point

you could try something like:

```
with open(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_output.csv", 'a', newline='') as fp:            
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fp)
    # Iterating requests for each row
    for row in df.itertuples():
        # Request info and manipulate its response
        # ... code ...
        # Finally, append the data to file
        csv_writer.writerow(output_list)
```

The main reason for this second hint is because opening a file is a time consuming operation. Thus, you should try to open that file once and write multiple times.

Note that I haven't run this code as far as I haven't got any sample of that data. So, it's just a hint about common ways to improve performance

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @Almasyx's answer regarding opening the file once, and @Random Davis' comment regarding parallelization, you can also remove the print statements to obtain substantial speedups. Another minor improvement would be to store your `r['Records'][0]` as a variable and using that in subsequent lines. Or else you are repeatedly indexing a list within a dictionary.

Also, based on the size of your REST API call response objects, you can store them all as a list. And only at the end, go through them one after another while writing to the CSV file.